# Cómo ejecutar dos comandos en cmd desde Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Al poner esto en el **CMD** de windows si me funciona:
`C:\Users\ismar>cd Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProyectoAutomatas2\src`

`C:\Users\ismar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProyectoAutomatas2\src>dot -Tpng prueba.txt -o prueba.png`

pero no tengo idea de como ponerlo en java para que lo haga. 
el segundo comando depende del primero.

```
public void EjecutarCMD()
{

try {
    // Execute a command without arguments
    String command = "cd Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProyectoAutomatas2\src";
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: puedes ejecutar un comando, y luego ejecutar el otro (como haces en la consola). Simplemente repite las lineas de String command = ... Process child  = ... child.Runtime... pero con el otro comando.

Comment: De hecho, podría simplemente encadenar los comandos: `"cd dir ; dot ..."`

Comment: Eso fue lo primero que intenté, por lógica sabrías que ya estás en la dirección donde se encuentra el archivo y al ejecutar el otro comando ya debería cargarme el otro archivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que lo que se necesita es una tarea que permita hacer lo siguiente:

- Cambiar a un directorio específico.
- Dentro de ese directorio, se
  ejecuta un comando.

Como se comentó previamente, no se puede cambiar a un directorio dentro de un proceso Java, por lo que no funcionará el segundo comando.

Hay dos alternativas para resolver esto:
Crear un archivo por lotes (.bat o .cmd) y dentro de dicho archivo colocar los comandos que se requiere ejecutar.
Esto implicará que la línea en que se define el comando quedaría del siguiente modo:

El archivo .bat o .cmd quedaría con el siguiente contenido (deben indicarse rutas completas):

```
cd c:\users\xxxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProyectoAutomatas2\src
dot -Tpng prueba.txt -o prueba.png
```

Y el código Java para invocar dicho archivo (línea en que se define el comando), queda del siguiente modo:

```
String command = "c:\\turutacompleta\\comando.cmd";
```

La segunda alternativa sería (considerando que el comando dot y los archivos están en la ruta "..\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProyectoAutomatas2\src", en la línea del código Java se puede indicar la ruta completa (lo que evita tener que utilizar el comando cd).

En este caso, la línea queda del siguiente modo:

```
String command = "c:\users\xxxx\documents\dot.exe -Tpng c:\users\xxxx\documents\prueba.txt -o c:\users\xxxx\documents\prueba.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que no sabes es cómo sacar la salida de los comandos por pantalla ya que la ejecución de los mismos ya la tienes.

Para sacar la salida de los comandos que ejecutas por pantalla simplemente utiliza su input stream de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExecCMD{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    ejecutarCMD(comando1);
    ejecutarCMD(comando2);
  }

  public static void ejecutarCMD(String cmd){
    Process p;
    try {
      p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
      p.waitFor();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      String line = "";
      while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }
      reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Si esta no es la respuesta que buscabas, intenta por favor especificar un poco más. Estaré encantado de ayudarte.

**EDITADO:** En Java no puedes cambiar el directorio de trabajo en el que un proceso se inicia al no existir el ejecutable del mandato "cd". Por esta razón,no tienes que ejecutar dos comandos sino solamente uno pero indicando el directorio de trabajo correcto.
Para hacer esto, en la instrucción `Runtime.exec()` utiliza la versión del método que tiene 3 parámetros en vez de la que sólo tiene 1. Te dejo aquí el [enlace a la documentación](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File)).

Comment: Probé tu código y me lanzó un error, trataré de detallar más lo que quiero lograr. Estoy haciendo un autómata  en java, pero para graficar el autómata estoy utilizando una librería llamada "Automaton", me genera un txt con los estados iniciales del automata. luego esa imagen la quiero convertir a png. es alli donde utilizo el "dot -Tpng prueba.txt -o prueba.png" pero antes de esto debo situarme en la carpeta donde tengo prueba.txt que esta en la direccion "cd Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProyectoAutomatas2\src"

Pero no me funciona. nunca me convierte el archivo de txt a png

Comment: Vale, ahora entiendo mejor. Pero, ¿qué error te da?

Comment: Cuando ejecuto tu código me lanza error en ésta línea "p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);" me imagino que no ingresa a la dirección a la que tiene que ejecutar en el cmd

Comment: Podrías por favor enseñarme la traza de la excepción? No tengo el JDK instalado en esta máquina así que no he podido probarlo.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
 at Principal.EjecutarCMD(Principal.java:38)
 at Principal.jButton1ActionPerformed(Principal.java:115)
 at Principal.access$000(Principal.java:15)
 at Principal$1.actionPerformed(Principal.java:78)

Estos son los errores amigo

Comment: Fallo mío. No me dí cuenta al escribirlo que en Java no se puede cambiar de directorio al no existir un ejecutable del comando "cd". En Java, cada mandato que ejecutas se inicia en un proceso diferente que tiene su propio directorio de trabajo así como sus propias variables de entorno. Edito mi respuesta para ponerte cómo deberías hacerlo. Y para la próxima vez, incluye en la pregunta la traza de la excepción que te tira desde es principio :)